# How to change Crystal Reports measurement units in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I've read that units in CR are displayed in TWIPS, but I can't find a way to change that nor in VS nor in CR.
I need to set left and top properties of fields in CR in centimeters.
Any idea how to do that?

tnx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Units are recorded in TWIPs internally in Crystal, but are usually displayed in either inches or centimetres in the report designer, depending on the location specified in the Windows Control Panel.

To check, try opening the report designer for any report, then File | Page Setup... to see which units are used for the page margins.

Comment: You were wright about location settings, now units in page setup are in cm after I set it to my country, but left top width and height properties are still in twips or something. Is that supposed to be like that? Could it be displayed in centimeters or millimeters?

Comment: If you are accessing the left, top, width and height properties via the API, then I suspect that they are meant to be like that (as that is how Crystal stores them internally). If you are accessing those values within the report designer (by right-clicking on the field and selecting the Size and Position... menu option), they should appear in the same units as the page margin - ie. cm.